# Styling ListBoxItem's of nested ListBoxes [WPF]

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` with `ListBoxItem`s that contains a nested `ListBox`. Now I want the top-level `ListBox`'s items to not have a blue background then they are selected (see pic).

[Example Image http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/237/window1.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/237/window1.png)

I tried to use the XAML below with a style to change the background color to transparent as descibed in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/08/31/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox.aspx). This works, but it also changes the selected background color of the items in the nested `ListBox`. How do I change it to only apply to the top-level items?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="352">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleItemTemplate">
                <Border Margin="5" Background="Gray" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.BitmapEffect>
                        <DropShadowBitmapEffect/>
                    </Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <StackPanel Margin="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Lid, StringFormat='ProvID: {0}'}"/>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestOrders}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button Height="23" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Margin="0,0,12,12" Click="button1_Click">Button</Button>
        <ListBox Name="listBox1" Margin="12,12,12,41" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SampleItemTemplate}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I understand that this style applies to all objects of type `ListBoxItem`, but how do I get it to apply only to items in listbox1?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Probably there is a better way to accomplish what I want, in that case, please tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need both the "inner" and "outer" items to be selectable? I would probably stick with ItemsControl for the outer list and just let the inner items be selectable. Then you could style ListBoxItem without affecting the "outer" items.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Matt (looks like you can just stick an `ItemsControl` inside a `ScrollViewer` for the main list), but you can also reset the colors back to their defaults inside the scope for the child `ListBox`es:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}"/>
```