# how to create a Visual studio 2012 chat box control?

Tags: windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, chat

I am making an app using visual studio 2012, It can be both in metro style or windows form I just need a control that behaves like the place where your message appears once you send it... like the one in the Message app on windows 8 and like iphone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard WPF Listbox with some customization to the list items is all it takes. [Like it's done in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1113548/736079).

No need for any 3rd party control.

Answer (score 0):

There are three way´s:

1. One is using the Rich-Textbox->more difficult, but looks better
2. Or the normal text box
3. Or making your own text box-element